# ng-repeat show data randomly

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I have json object data which is returned from database. My json object's demo is given below::

```
 $scope.info = [
   {
     "num": 1,
     "col1": "demo1",
     "col2": "demoX1"
   },
   {
     "num": 2,
     "col1": "demo2",
     "col2": "demoX2",
   },
   ................................
   ................................ 
   {
     "num": 15,
     "col1": "demo15",
     "col2": "demoX15",
   }
   .................................
   ................................   
];
```

**php::**

```
 <?php
     // sorted by num
     $sql = "SET @num:=0; SELECT @num:=@num+1 AS num, t.* FROM table as t";
     //convert array data to json data
     $getData = json_encode(GetAllDataFromServer($sql));
 ?>
```

**html::**

```
 <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="dbItem in info | slice: itemNum: currentItem">
         <td>{{dbItem.num}}</td>
         <td>{{others}}</td>
      </tr>
 </table>

  <pagination total-items="info.length" ng-model="currentItem" max-size="7" class="pagination" boundary-links="true" items-per-page="15"></pagination>

 <script>
     angular.module("App")
       .controller("NamController", function($scope)  {
            // json data from database
            $scope.info = <?=$getData ?>;

            $scope.currentItem = 1; 
            $scope.itemNum = 15;
       });
 </script>
```

when I show **$scope.info** json data in ng-repeat, it shows data randomly not based on **num**.

**Sample output::**

```
num  -  col1   -  col2
---------------------------
1    -  demo1   -  demoX1
15   -  demo15  -  demoX15
9    -  demo9   -  demoX9
............................
............................
```

I have done some test, after returning data from **slice** filter, data shows randomly.

**js:: (slice filter)**

```
myApp.filter('slice', function() {
   return function(arr, itemNum, current) {
      var lt = ((current-1)*itemNum);
      var gt = +lt + +itemNum;
      var data = {};
      i = 0;
      angular.forEach(arr, function(val, index) {            
         if ( index >= lt && index < gt ) {
            data[i++] = val;
        }
      });
      return data;
   };
});
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

**Edit::**

**js:: (slice filter Edit)**

```
myApp.filter('slice', function() {
   return function(arr, itemNum, current) {
      var begin = ((current-1)*itemNum);
      var end = +begin  + +itemNum;        
      return arr.slice(begin, end);
   };
});
```

**Still no solution**

Comment: I think you should edit your SQL to sort data by num column.

Comment: sql data is correct, problem occurs after filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

**html::**

```
 <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="dbItem in info | startFrom:(currentItem-1)*itemNum | limitTo:itemNum">  
     <td>{{dbItem.num}}</td>
     <td>{{others}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

 <pagination total-items="info.length" ng-model="currentItem" max-size="7" class="pagination" boundary-links="true" items-per-page="{{itemNum}}"></pagination>
```

**js:**

```
 myApp.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
       start = +start; //parse to int
       return input.slice(start);
    }
 });
```

For further read  https://gist.github.com/kmaida/06d01f6b878777e2ea34

Answer (score 1):

Use 'orderBy' filter that is provided by angularjs.

```
<tr ng-repeat="dbItem in info | slice: itemNum: currentItem | orderBy:'num'">
         <td>{{dbItem.num}}</td>
         <td>{{others}}</td>
      </tr>
```

I hope this helps. Please refer the following documentation about orderBy filter
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a jsfiddle or plnkr.

Comment: Why are you using 'slice' filter ? What is the purpose of it ?

Comment: For limiting the elements to show, you can use 'limitTo' filter.

Answer (score 0):

It's all but random. Your data is encoded in JSON format, and JSON keys cannot be integers, they are strings. So your data looks like :

```
{"1" : "demo1" , "2" : "demo2" , "15" : "demo15"}
```

and not :

```
{1 : "demo1" , 2 : "demo2" , 15 : "demo15"}
```

So strings are sorted as strings, not numbers, which yields :

```
"1" - "15" - "2" - "25" - "3" - "35"
```

(They are sorted according to the first character, not the numerical value.)

I believe the solution is to ask MySQL to sort data by NUM, so the encoded JSON is already like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Send a JSON array instead of a JSON object, arrays would preserve the order. JSON parsing arranges properties alphabetically

instead of

```
 {"1":"something","3":"something else"}
```

send

```
 [{"id":1,"data":"something"},{"id":3,"data":"something else"}]
```

from the server. and it won't break the order when the JSON object is parsed.